# "select count(*)" returns different result in and outside PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, count

I have table and sequence:

```
create table sometable (
  id number(10) not null,
  application varchar2(255 char) not null,
  constraint sometable_pk primary key (id)
);

create sequence sometable_seq minvalue 1 start with 1 increment by 1 cache 10;
```

And PL/SQL procedure that suppose do insert into table but first check if such entry already exist and throw custom ORA-20000 error if that is the case:

```
create or replace 
procedure dosth 
(
  application in varchar2
)
is
  l_cnt integer := 0;
begin
  select count(*) into l_cnt from sometable s where s.application = application;
  dbms_output.put_line('count ' || l_cnt );
  if (l_cnt = 0) then 
    insert into sometable (id, application) values (sometable_seq.nextval, application);
  else
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'application already exist:' || application);
  end if;
end dosth;
/
```

When I call PL/SQL:

```
begin
  dosth('app1');
end;
/
```

I receive:

```
anonymous block completed
count 0
```

All OK as there is no such entry in the table. Second call with same argument as expected:

```
ORA-20000: application already exist:app1
count 1
```

But what is strange is that consecutive calls using different argument values result in the same error.

```
begin
  dosth('app2');
end;
/
ORA-20000: application already exist:app2
count 1
```

Of course there is no such entry in the table and

```
select count(*) from sometable s where s.application = 'app2';
```

returns 0 and not 1 as inside PL/SQL procedure!

It is really confusing.. probably sth really silly. Please help.

Comment: In condition use procedure name: `... where s.application = DOSTH.application` or use unique constraint, like @Mat said.

Comment: Thx for hints. I dont wan't to use unique constraint as I need custom ORA-20000 error. This is just a sample of more complex code to narrow down the problem I have. I will try to rename parameter or use procedure name but .. this is still confusing and I don't get why it works like that.

Comment: It's not working because you check this like `where application = application`. Count returns number of all rows.

Comment: @GrzegorzM Such behavior is described in the documentation. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/nameresolution.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. To fix it as you pointed out I had to change this line:

```
select count(*) into l_cnt from sometable s where s.application = application;
```

into

```
select count(*) into l_cnt from sometable s where s.application = dosth.application;
```

although it is counter intuitive (at list for me) seems that this is the way PL/SQL works.